# Add drop-shadow to SVG element programmatically

Tags: javascript, svg, dropshadow

I am using JavaScript to add circles to inline SVG. How can I style those circles to include a drop-shadow effect?

I found the [drop-shadow() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()) but apparently it doesn't apply to individual SVG elements.

I also found the SVG filter element and how it can be included manually in the code under defs. But in my case the SVG is retrieved at runtime and I need to add the shadow programmatically.

```
<filter id="shadow">
  <feDropShadow dx="0.2" dy="0.4" stdDeviation="0.2"/>
</filter>
```

[update] I am almost there. What I don't understand is why my shadow is cropped to fit in a square.
[image: cropped shadow]

My code:

```
// Add the drop-shadow effect
let defs = document.createElementNS(NS, 'defs');
let filter = document.createElementNS(NS, 'filter');
filter.setAttribute("id", "dropshadow");

let feDropShadow = document.createElementNS(NS, 'feDropShadow');
feDropShadow.setAttribute("dx", "0");
feDropShadow.setAttribute("dy", "0");
feDropShadow.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "2");

draw.appendChild(defs);
defs.appendChild(filter);
filter.appendChild(feDropShadow);
```

Comment: Sure it applies to individual elements, try it in Firefox. Other browsers may need to catch up.

Comment: thx. I am hoping for a solution supported by at least a couple modern browsers (Chrome or new Edge for example).

Comment: Construct and insert the element as you would any other element.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'll try that, thanks. So should I insert a "defs" element then append my "filter" elements?

Comment: Yes, but maybe check to see if the svg already has a `<defs>` and use that if it exists.

Comment: @Ouroborus thx for the help! I have updated the post as I still have a little issue. Feel free to post your comments as answer.

Comment: I also addressed my cropping issue with filter width and height.